# NTFS partitions mount as root instead of user as set in /etc/fstab

Tags: 12.04, ntfs, fstab, udev

I recently upgraded a server to Ubuntu 12.04 with a fresh install and my NTFS partitions won't mount as user at boot but I can mount them as user manually from the console with `$ sudo mount -a`. Using `ntfsfix` reports no problems and `chkdisk` sees nothing wrong under Windows 7.  Are the drives not ready to be mounted at boot and default to root instead of user for some reason?

Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=E4E6B30CE6B2DDCC  /media/Bowles        ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022  0  0
UUID=A040C42340C3FDD2  /media/Burroughs     ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022  0  0
UUID=EA022C73022C46C3  /media/DoctorGonzo   ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022  0  0
UUID=BA425A384259FA19  /media/Geist         ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022  0  0
UUID=E87CFAE57CFAAE06  /media/DouglasAdams  ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022  0  0
```

Here is the output of `ls -l` after boot:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 xbmc xbmc   4096 Oct 31 21:46 Bowles
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users  8192 Oct 31 21:46 Burroughs
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users  4096 Oct 28 21:45 DoctorGonzo
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users 12288 Oct 31 19:56 DouglasAdams
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users  4096 Nov  3 01:03 Geist
```

If I unmount and mount again with `$ sudo mount -a` from console, the output of `ls -l`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 xbmc xbmc  4096 Oct 31 21:46 Bowles
drwxr-xr-x 1 xbmc xbmc  8192 Oct 31 21:46 Burroughs
drwxr-xr-x 1 xbmc xbmc  4096 Oct 28 21:45 DoctorGonzo
drwxr-xr-x 1 xbmc xbmc 12288 Oct 31 19:56 DouglasAdams
drwxr-xr-x 1 xbmc xbmc  4096 Nov  3 01:03 Geist
```

---

### **Update**

I was fooling myself, I had a custom `udev` rule set up to auto-mount file systems by label for USB drives, borrowed from [here](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=116996&pid=1093119#pid1093119), but didn't update the rule to accommodate for my additional hard drives.  Updating the rule to auto-mount only drives after `/dev/sde` solved my problem.  Thank you again for your reply *cartoonist*.

Answer (score 1):

This may help. Mount your ntfs partition with these options:
`rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions`

For example in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=E4E6B30CE6B2DDCC  /media/Bowles  ntfs-3g rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,umask=022  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately it didn't work.  I'm wondering if my set up has something to do with it.  The first NTFS ,'/media/Bowles' is a partition on my boot drive, while the three other NTFS file systems are separate hard drives.  I think that's why the first mounts as it should while the others don't.  Is there a way to delay mounting of the other filesystems in '/etc/fstab'?  Or, could I mount from '/etc/rc.local' post boot?